# click yii2 gridview linkpager's page no, jump error

Tags: yii, yii2, cgridview

the gridview if on right of the page,left is some menus,when click on page no 2，it dose not only refresh the gridview，but all page including left part are lost——a totally new page come out！help~

there is the debugging Screenshot：
[image: before click]
[image: after click next page]

my action is

```
public function actionList()
{
 $model = new Loan();
 $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $model->find(),
    'pagination' => [
                    'pagesize' => '1',
     ],
 ]);

  return $this->renderPartial('list', ['model' => $model, 'dataProvider' => $dataProvider]);
}
```

my view is：

```
<?php
use yii\grid\GridView;
use yii\grid\SerialColumn;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\widgets\LinkPager;
?>
<?=GridView::widget([
         'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
     'layout'=> '{items}{pager}',
         'columns' => [
             ['attribute' =>'loan_type','label'=>'借款类型','options' => ['width' => '80']],
                 ['attribute' =>'amount','label'=>'金额','options' => ['width' => '80']],
                 ['attribute' =>'rate','label'=>'还款利率','options' => ['width' => '80']],
                 ['attribute' =>'fee','label'=>'手续费','options' => ['width' => '80']],  
             ['attribute' =>'status','label'=>'状态','options' => ['width' => '80']   ],
             ['attribute' =>'comment','label'=>'审核意见','options' => ['width' => '80']],
             ['attribute' => 'created_at','value' =>function($model){return date('Y-m-d',strtotime($model->created_at));},'label'=>'申请时间','options' => ['width' => '150']],

                 [
                 'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                 'header' => '操作',
                 'template' => '{audit}',
                 'buttons' => [
                    'audit' => function ($url,$model) {
                    return Html::a('<span id="xxxx" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>','#',['title'=>'审核',
    'onclick'=>"
             $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'text',
                    url: 'http://182.92.4.87:8000/index.php?r=loan/pj', //目标地址
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {alert(XMLHttpRequest.status + ':' + XMLHttpRequest.statusText); },
                    success: function (page)
                    {
                        $('.ucRight').html(page);
                    }
             });
         return false;",
    ]);},
                  ],
                     'urlCreator' => function ($action, $model, $key, $index) {
                            return Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl(['loan/list','id' => $model->status]);
             },            
             'headerOptions' => ['width' => '80'],
                 ],
      ],
]);
?>
```

Comment: It's impossible to help without seeing the actual code.

Comment: updated，please see it again~many thx

Comment: Do you simply want pagination in `GridView` without page reload? Why not to simply use built-in `Pjax` for these purposes?

Comment: not just i want no-reloading. I am thinking how to bind linkpager page-turing events(how to configure the linkpager class) with the gridview refresh?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your problem is that you haven't prevented the html link from directing to a new page, so your user is clicking on the link, which then loads a new page with the contents returned by the server; in this case a page of information with no layout applied. You need to add event.preventDefault() before the ajax call to stop this behaviour.

However, as @arogachev said, if you simply want to use pagination without a page refresh, then just use pjax. That is what pjax is designed for,